# How do I space out the numbers from the letters in this set of dimensions?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, how do I separate

```
9.13x4.5x1.0
```

So that it becomes

```
9.13 x 4.5 x 1.0
```

And so I can do that with any set of unspaced dimensions with three numbers and x's.

Comment: formula: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"x"," x "),"  "," ")`

Comment: Whats the second substitute for? Seems like you're replacing a blank space with a blank space?

Comment: @nbayly it is replacing double spaces with a single, in case the text already has a space already like `9.13 x4.5 x1.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dimensions are in `column A`,

enter this formula in `column B`,

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"x"," x ")
```